# Problems with index position of angular momentum

Tags: angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, covariance, poisson-brackets

I want to calculate the poisson bracket of two angular momentum components:
$$\{L^i,L^j\}=\frac{\partial\epsilon^{\:i\:m}_{\:\:l}q^lp_m}{\partial q^k} \frac{\partial\epsilon_{\:\:s}^{\:j\:r}q^sp_r}{\partial p_k}-\frac{\partial\epsilon^{\:i\:m}_{\:\:l}q^lp_m}{\partial p_k} \frac{\partial\epsilon_ {\:\:s}^{\:j\:r} q^sp_r}{\partial q^k}$$
Which gives:
$$\{L^i,L^j\}= \epsilon^{\:i\:m}_{\:\:k} \epsilon_{\:\:s}^{\:j\:k}p_mq^s- \epsilon^{\:i\:k}_{\:\:l} \epsilon_{\:\:k}^{\:j\:r}p_rq^l $$
But then I get problems with the index positions if I want to convert the Levi-Civita-Tensors into Kronecker-Deltas. Is angular momentum defined different in general coordinate systems or where else is the problem?

Comment: In flat space upper and lower index positions are not distinguishable. Are you comfortable with [contracting Levi-Civita symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Three_dimensions_2)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos My problem is that if I contract the Levi-Civita tensors in the first term I would get $\epsilon^{\:\:im}_{k} \epsilon_{\:\:s}^{\:k\:j}=\delta^i_s\delta^{mj}-\delta^{ij}\delta^{m}_s $ but then the Kronecker deltas have not always one upper and one lower index.

Comment: Raising and lowering indices is meaningless here for a flat metric. Try ignoring the distinction first, to get to  the important result, and finesse the upper-lower (non)issue later!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks but deriving the result is no problem. My question is just how I have to write the angular momentum components that I get no problems with the index position.

Comment: Upper and lower indices are equivalent in this space. Use flat metrics $\delta_jk$  to take them all up and follow the contractions. Are you completely comfortable with the WP page? It has mixed $\delta$s.

Comment: @CosmasZachos so does that mean that the definition $L_i:=\epsilon_{ijk}q^jg^{lk}p_l$ is only true in flat spaces or is the result of the poisson bracket different in curved spaces ?

Comment: Ach, if the issue is non-flat phase-spaces, you might as well have gone there up front. A couple of linked questions here include [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/179422/) and [that](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/430544/)....

Comment: Besides generalizing the Levi-Civita tensor/symbol to curved space, another issue is that in curved space the position coordinates $q^j$ are no longer components of a vector.